# Firebase cloud function for file upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have this cloud function that I wrote to upload file to google cloud storage:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename:'2fe4e3d2bfdc.json'});

var filePath = file.path + "/" + file.name;

    return bucket.upload(filePath, {
        destination: file.name
    }).catch(reason => {
            console.error(reason);
    });
```

I used `formidable` to parse the uploaded file and I tried to log the properties of the uploaded file and it seems fine; it is uploaded to a temp dir `'/tmp/upload_2866bbe4fdcc5beb30c06ae6c3f6b1aa/` but when I try to upload the file to the gcs am getting this error:

```
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/tmp/upload_2866bbe4fdcc5beb30c06ae6c3f6b1aa/thumb_ttttttt.jpg'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/tmp/upload_2866bbe4fdcc5beb30c06ae6c3f6b1aa/thumb_ttttttt.jpg' }
```

I am using this html form to upload the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://us-central1-appname.cloudfunctions.net/uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't got the right permission to do that.

Comment: yeah, I cant access the temp file that I upload.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I got a solution from the ***Firebase Support Team***

So first thing:

```
var filePath = file.path + "/" + file.name;
```

we dont need the file.name since the `file.path` is full path of the file (including the file name).

So changed it to this instead:

```
var filePath = file.path;
```

Second, the function terminates before the asynchronous work in 'form.parse(...)' is completed. That means the actual file upload might still be in progress while the function execution has ended.

The fix for that is to wrap the `form.parse(...)` in a promise:

```
exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
       var file = files.fileToUpload;
       if(!file){
         reject("no file to upload, please choose a file.");
         return;
       }
       console.info("about to upload file as a json: " + file.type);
       var filePath = file.path;
       console.log('File path: ' + filePath);
 
       var bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket-name');
       return bucket.upload(filePath, {
           destination: file.name
       }).then(() => {
         resolve();  // Whole thing completed successfully.
       }).catch((err) => {
         reject('Failed to upload: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
       });
     });
   }).then(() => {
     res.status(200).send('Yay!');
     return null
   }).catch(err => {
     console.error('Error while parsing form: ' + err);
     res.status(500).send('Error while parsing form: ' + err);
   });
 });
```

Lastly, you may want to consider using the Cloud Storage for Firebase in uploading your file instead of Cloud functions. Cloud Storage for Firebase allows you to upload files directly to it, and would work much better:

1. It has access control
2. It has resumable uploads/downloads (great for poor connectivity)
3. It can accept files of any size without timeout-issues
4. If you want to trigger a Cloud Function on file upload even, you can
   do that and a lot more

Comment: Can you still use Formidable for file uploads if you use Cloud Storage for Firebase? Can you use this with the local Firebase server too?

Comment: Yes I tried it with google cloud storage and it works, but I have not tried with local firebase server.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell how you use Formidable on the Node.js server to do this?

Comment: The above code is compelete code of the cloud function, if you have tried functions yet please check here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Ah, thanks. I missed that Formidable was used in the Promise!

Comment: Note: `fileToUpload` seems now to be `upload`.

Comment: Just tried to use a Promise for uploading to a file system file. That does not work (timeout) so the crucial part seems to be to use gcs. Thanks for help!

Comment: I can't get the upload to a bucket to work either. Please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719366/uploading-to-google-cloud-storage-with-node-js

Comment: I have tried to use the same snippet in answer, but it hangs until the function timesout. `form.parse` gets called but the callback in it never gets called. When I use eg `multer` or `multiparty` I always get `Stream ended unexpectedly`.

Comment: Also experience the form.parse callback never being called. Does  anyone have an explanation why this is not working on Firebase?

Comment: To use this in Firebase you need to use the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-serverless

Comment: The formidable developers have said support for serverless will be integrated and handled in the next major release, see https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/issues/657

Answer (score 2):

I managed this by *downloading* the file to the `tmp` instead.

You will need:

```
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');
```

Then, inside `onChange`. I created `tempLocalDir` like so:

```
const LOCAL_TMP_FOLDER = '/tmp/';
const fileDir = (the name of the file); //whatever method you choose to do this
const tempLocalDir = `${LOCAL_TMP_FOLDER}${fileDir}`;
```

Then I use mkdirp to make the temp directory

```
return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
// Then Download file from bucket.
const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
return bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: tempLocalFile
}).then(() => {
    console.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
    //Here I have some code that converts images then returns the converted image
    //Then I use
    return bucket.upload((the converted image), {
        destination: (a file path in your database)
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('JPEG image uploaded to Storage at', filePath);
    })//You can perform more actions of end the promise here
```

I think my code achieves that you were trying to accomplish. I hope this helps; I can offer more code if necessary.