# Uploading to google cloud storage with Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, authorization, google-cloud-storage

Struggling with Node.js and Google cloud. I am trying to upload a file to a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. Basically I am using the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253054/324691, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

// form.maxFieldsSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // default
form.maxFieldsSize = 20 * 1024;
// form.maxFileSize = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
// 4 MB / minute, 1 hour
form.maxFileSize = 4 * 60 * 1024 * 1024;
// Limit to 10 minutes during tests (4 MB/minute)
form.maxFileSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
form.maxFileSize = 4 * 10 * 1024 * 1024;

form.encoding = 'utf-8';
form.keepExtensions = true;
form.type = 'multipart';

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.warn("form.parse callback", err, fields, files);
        if (err) {
            reject(new Error(err));
            return;
        }
        var file = files.upload;
        if(!file){
            reject(new Error("no file to upload, please choose a file."));
            return;
        }
        console.info("about to upload file as a json: " + file.type);
        var filePath = file.path;
        console.log('File path: ' + filePath);
        console.log('File name: ' + file.name);

        var bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
        console.info("typeof bucket.upload", typeof bucket.upload);
        bucket.upload(filePath, {
            destination: file.name
        }).then(() => {
            resolve(true);  // Whole thing completed successfully.
            return true;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.warn("catch bucket.upload, err", err);
            reject(new Error('Failed to upload: ' + JSON.stringify(err)));
        });
        console.warn("After bucket.upload");
    });
    console.warn("After form.parse");
}).then(() => {
    console.warn("form.parse then");
    res.status(200).send('Yay!');
    return true;
}).catch(err => {
    console.warn("form.parse catch");
    console.error('Error while parsing form: ' + err);
    res.status(500).send('Error while parsing form: ' + err);
});
```

The output in the console log looks ok (including file.path and file.name), but when it gets to `bucket.upload` (which is of type `function`) then it crashes with the error `Error while parsing form: Error: Failed to upload: {"message":"Error during request."}`. And then it says `Execution took 1910 ms, user function completed successfully`. And after that finally `Function worker killed by signal: SIGTERM`.

I have been testing using `bucketName` with and without "gs://".

And I have been testing different ways for authorization:

```
const storage = new Storage({ projectId: projectId });
const storage = new Storage({ keyFileName: 'path-to-keyfile.json'});
const storage = new Storage();
```

The key file is a key file for the service account (see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

This is a Firebase project and I am testing on the local Firebase server (`firebase serve --only functions,hosting`).

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication of the storage should look like this:

```
const storage = new Storage({
    apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL",
    projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID"
});
```

Also working with multipart looks different than with local files. So the code for uploading would be:

```
            const fileName = 'file_name.extension";

            const fileUpload = bucket.file(fileName);

            const uploadStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                    contentType: file.mimetype
                }
            });


            uploadStream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            });

            uploadStream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('Upload success');
            });

            uploadStream.end(file.buffer);
```

Lastly, bucketName shouldn't contain gs:// - it should look like this: **project_id.appspot.com**.

> Ps. Uploading mimetype was handled with **busboy** in the code above.

Comment: Thanks Gertriax. I think the multipart part is ok since I am using that for normal file upload. (Maybe I should check for typos...) How do you know authorization should look like this?

Comment: And what kind of authorization is it?

Comment: I know about authorization because I was myself using firebase and cloud services. So I was also trying to make this work and I did manage to do so. Here is Github with the code that is working https://github.com/Getriax/toplance. This authorization is from the firebase site https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0. However, I think json file should also work but I gave you the example that is working for me.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. That authorization config is for the client JavaScript for communicating with the server. I tested it in Node.js (in Firebase), but I get the same error message, unfortunately. So now I will have a look at your code to try to understand the crucial difference with my code. Just to be sure: Is your code working today (there might be issues with Firebase)?

Comment: Ah, it works! :-) -- I found the solution with your help! The problem was a trailing "/" in the bucket name. (No authorization setup is necessary, just use `const storage = new Storage();`.) Your help saved me a lot of work, actually.

Comment: Eh, Google could have been quite a bit more helpful. They should be taking care of for example `"gs://my-bucket/"`.

Comment: The code is working as it was written 2 weeks ago :) I have also found that Google documentation isn't quite up to date, especially the firebase part. However, I didn't expect that no authorization was required for uploading files. Anyways glad I could have helped :-)

Comment: My understanding is that the code runs under the service account for the project. But authorization is always tricky so I thought there was something wrong when things did not work as I expected. (BTW, it would be nice if Google offered a command to list authorization etc for the running process.)

Comment: According to google cloud documentation if you don't specify credentials during client construction it will look for them in your environment. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/auth.js. So I guess you are right :-) Also there is google's command line https://cloud.google.com/sdk/, but I'm not sure if there is a command for the task that you have mentioned.

Comment: AFAIK You do not need to specifiy credentials when running the nodejs instance on Google Compute Engine, rather only need them when you run your nodejs instance somewere else, like locally or a different server.