# firebase function with formidable has the file object undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, formidable

```
 exports.storePostData = functions.https.onRequest(function (request, 
response) {
cors(request, response, function () {
var uuid = UUID();
var formData = new formidable.IncomingForm();

formData.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {

  fs.rename(files.file.path, '/tmp/' + files.file.name);
  var bucket = gcs.bucket('pwagram-87530.appspot.com');

  bucket.upload('/tmp/' + files.file.name, {
    uploadType: 'media',
    metadata: {
      metadata: {
        contentType: files.file.type,
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
      }
    }
  }, function(err, file) {

    if (!err) {
      admin.database().ref('posts').push({
        id: fields.id,
        title: fields.title,
        location: fields.location,
        rawLocation: {
          lat: fields.rawLocationLat,
          lng: fields.rawLocationLng
        },
        image: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/' + bucket.name 
        + '/o/' + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + '?alt=media&token=' + uuid
      })
```

the function log is throwing the error "cannot read property path of 
undefined", which i guess is from the fact that the formidable files object 
is empty..will appreciate if anyone could help. i can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098305/firebase-cloud-function-for-file-upload/45253054

Comment: Recommend using busboy instead for file uploads. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data_and_file_uploads