# How do i upload a file to firebase storage using a firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I searched and found tons of super complex examples about using firebase storage, but none about doing it from a cloud function.. I need something to upload a simple file to a bucket

Comment: On which platform, Android, React, Angular or What?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098305/firebase-cloud-function-for-file-upload

Comment: Can you explain your question with a bit more details?

Comment: Neither of those platforms.. I would like to deploy a cloud function on firebase so it's in node is, but inside a function