# How to upload an image with google gloud functions and google storage?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Can someone tell me how I can upload an image on Firebase Storage? I would apriciate if someone can give me an code sample how to that with Typescript and Node.js.

I have already created an Firebase project. How many giga Bytes you may upload for free?

this is my Client API endpoint written with Retrofit:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/uploadImage")
fun uploadFile(@Part("description") description: RequestBody, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part, @Query("idUser") idUser: String): Observable<ResponseBody>
```

At the moment I use something like that, but not working for me:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')


exports.uploadImage = functions.https.onRequest(async (request:any,response:any) => {
  // params
  const file = request.query.file
  const idUser = request.query.idUser
  const description = request.query.description

  console.log("idUser: " + idUser + ", description: " + description)



  const storageRef = storage.bucket('gs://<project>')
  const finalDestination = storageRef.child("/FCMImages");

  // const metadata = {
  //   contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  // };

  storageRef.upload(file, {destination: finalDestination});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials and documentation that you can follow to perform upload of images to Firebase.

I would recommend you to take a look at the following links, to confirm if they might help you achieve it. In case they don't, let me know, so I can assist you further.

- [Firebase cloud function for file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098305/firebase-cloud-function-for-file-upload)
- [Image processing using Google Cloud function](https://medium.com/@parthaxbhattacharya/image-processing-using-google-cloud-function-10e65eb19d61)

The first one is a post here, on the Community, with some codes and solution on how to do it and the second one is a post on Medium, about processing and working images with Cloud Functions.

Let me know if the information helped you!