# Google Cloud Function , node js , file upload not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am new to cloud functions , I need to save files to temp and process it , for some reason it works on my local machine but does not in function.
This is my functions :

```
 const express = require('express');
const  multer  = require('multer');
const  path = require('path');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/tmp/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)) //Appending extension
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const app = express();




app.post('/upload', upload.single('avatar'),(req, res,next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    console.log(typeof (filePath));

    res.status(200).send(filePath);
});

app.listen();
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "Puputer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.1.7-alpha.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "puppeteer": "^3.0.1",
    "puppeteer-page-proxy": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

**Updated** 
I have  changed to multer and seems it should work now , but I am not saving file to any place my req.file is undefined.(Works on local machine)

Comment: you are uploading file on server?? and did you try multer?

Comment: @Stamos There is a screenshot of postman request

Comment: @SaadSohail  I am saving file to /temp/  I found that's one place where the file can be saved, but the problem is that the request does not see files to this. No , I have not  .

Comment: i have tried express-upload but i faced many problems so i suggest you try to use multer for uploading files

Comment: @RomanHrybinchuk check this answer [Mutipart/form-data to JSON in Node.js using Busboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253054/2520974)

Comment: Don't forget to post how you fixed it as an answer and mark it as correct! This helps for visibility when other people encounter issues similar to yours.

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems u can't use multer or library like that to upload file via multipart form data. here is the solution https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data